# Chamomile lawn feed & winter care

Tags: lawn, winter-gardening

I have a Chamomile lawn that in its 2nd year is beginning to look the business.

Was wondering if there is a recommended 'feed' for it.

Also wondering how much care i should take regarding winter and frost danger?
(is it hardy enough to survive?)

Comment: Where do you live and what are the winters like there?

Comment: Surely, if its in its second year, it's already been through one winter, hasn't it?

Comment: Live in Kernow UK - winters are usually mild but ground frost can occur without warning.
Last year was an untypically mild winter & the unestablished lawn didnt feel as important to be as this year :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the chamomile I've ever seen in my lifetime really seemed to appreciate growing in nutrient-poor and well-drained conditions, often poking up in the middle of a rocky-dirt roadway. It always seemed very hardy in nature to me, but definitely something that prefers abundant sunshine.

It must be a very nice and low-maintenance ground cover as well as having that nice smell and pretty little yellow flowers :)